# Show list of wishlist members in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on wishlist in wordpress. I need to show list of all members of a specific level on my template page. Can anyone please help me how i can list all members. I have written this code. first i get the list of all wordpress users and then checking the level.

```
 <?php
        $wp_user_search = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, display_name FROM  $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID");
        foreach ( $wp_user_search as $userid ) {
            echo $user_id       = (int) $userid->ID;
            $user_login    = stripslashes($userid->user_login);
            $display_name  = stripslashes($userid->display_name);

            $return  = '';
            $return .= "\t" . '<li>'. $display_name .'</li>' . "\n";

             $check = wlmapi_is_user_a_member(1340726008, $user_id);
             if ( $check ) {
                  echo $user_id;
                  echo do_shortcode('[wlm_firstname]');
             } else {
                  echo 'User is not a member';
             }



        }
 ?>
```

Comment: So what does not work at this moment?

Comment: I am not getting all members list. I need to show member name and some custom fields which i added in my wishlist registration form.

Comment: can anyone help me that how i can show  wishlist members.